# Finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors from a linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

$T(a+bx) = a +4b + (a-2b)x$ from $P_1$ to $P_1$.

I'm trying to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this linear operator.

I'm pretty sure you need to find the matrix representation of the linear operator to start off but I'm already lost at that point.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the matrix representation is the surest way to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

**Hint:** To start you need a basis for $P_1$.  Any basis will do so I would choose the obvious one: $\{1, x\}$.  Next to find the matrix $A$ that represents $T$ with respect to this basis you need to remember the following: *The $i^\text{th}$ column of $A$ is the coordinate representation of $T(e_i)$ where $e_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ element in your basis.*

So the first and second columns of $A$ in your case are going to be the coordinate representations of $T(1)$ and $T(x)$ respectively.

Once you have written down $A$ you need to compute the characteristic polynomial and find it's roots to get the eigenvalues.  Then for each eigenvalue $\lambda$
$$T(a + bx) = \lambda a + \lambda bx$$
gives you a system of two equations whose solution set is the eigenspace for $\lambda$.